third party api integration error in laravel
For my ecommerce web app (laravel) im trying to use deep infra image recognition api called Model name: openai/clip-vit-large-patch14-336 .  when i integrated it there is a error called
"A 'contents' key is required" ,  and i cant find the solution.
this is my existing code :
   public function imageSearch(Request $request){
  try {
  $api = 'UMIDKJCkmZBRmCmmbzTWB8JPq3wMbd1b';
  // Instantiate a Guzzle HTTP client
  $client = new Client();

  $image = time().rand(1,1000).'.'.$request->image->extension();
  $request->image->move(public_path('search_images'),$image);

  $candidateLabels = ['cat', 'dog','phone','laptop'];
  $imagePath = public_path('search_images') . '/' . $image; // Assuming $image contains the filename

  $imageFile = fopen($imagePath, 'r');
  if (!$imageFile) {
  throw new Exception("Failed to open image file: $imagePath");
  }

  // Prepare the request body
  $body = [
     'multipart' => [
        [
              'name' => 'image',
              'contents' => fopen($imagePath, 'r'), // Read the image file
             
        ],
        [
              'name' => 'candidate_labels',
              'contents' => json_encode($candidateLabels),
        ],
     ],
  ];

  // Prepare the request headers
  $headers = [
     'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api,
  ];
  $response = $client->post('https://api.deepinfra.com/v1/inference/openai/clip-vit-base-patch32', [
     'headers' => $headers,
     'multipart' => $body,
 ]);

 // Handle the response
 $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
 $responseData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
 dd($responseData);
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return $th->getMessage();
  }
 

}

Are you certain you need the 'multipart' part in $body? Since there already is 'multipart' => $body

no,  this is HTTP/cURL API    curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: bearer $(deepctl auth token)"  
-F image=@my_image.jpg  
-F 'candidate_labels=["cat","dog"]'  
'https://api.deepinfra.com/v1/inference/openai/clip-vit-base-patch32'
